# Version Bootstrap 5 quick snippets 0.4.2 extension for Visual Studio Code

Tags: bootstrapper

I just installed the extension, mentioned in the title into the v 1.79 of VS Code.

It seems to work well, however, when I look at my code, it seems to be for Bootstrap 5.2, while I prefer to work with BS 5.3.

Is there any way I can let the extension adjust itself to 5.3, or is there an upgrade or another appropriate extension available, without me having to copy and paste the CSS and script links for BS 5.3 in all the time?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to (a) check the extension's web site / Github repo, or (b) contact the author directly to ask about this?